# How to block the IP that requests excessive 404 page not found?

Tags: log-messages

On my site often I see thousands of requests thats ends up 404 - page not found error.

How can I block the IP that exceeds more than certain number of requests within a span of time from Drupal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called fail2ban. There is a Drupal 7 module, but you would need to update it to Drupal OOP: https://www.drupal.org/project/fail2ban

But here's a recipe for integrating the [Honeypot module](http://dgo.to/honeypot) with fail2ban: https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/honeypot/integrate-honeypot-with-fail2ban